# Rails Query Based on Associated Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to find all EnrollmentPlans with a plan_type_id = 1 so I need to use the plan_id in the EnrollmentPlan table to get the plan_type_id from the Plan table in order to query the EnrollmentPlan table.

I have three models:

PlayType => `:id, :name`

Plan => `:id, :name, :plan_type_id`

EnrollmentPlan => `:id, :enrollment_id, :plan_id`

Associations:
EnrollmentPlan

```
belongs_to :plan
has_one :plan_type, through: :plan
```

Plan:

```
has_many :enrollment_plans
belongs_to :plan_type
```

I was trying queries like `EnrollmentPlan.joins(:plans).where(plans.plan_type_id: 1)` but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

The example they give is:

```
Author.joins(:articles).where(articles: { author: author })
```

So in your case:

```
EnrollmentPlan.joins(:plan).where(plans: { plan_type_id: 1 })
```

EDIT: As @steve stated, the above was for a has_many. Tweaked for a has_one relationship

Comment: This answer works when the relationship between Enrollment Plan and Plan is a `has_many :plans`, but in my example the relationship is `belongs_to :plan`, which results in `"Can't join EnrollmentPlan' to association named 'plans'; perhaps you misspelled it?"` - I'm using rails 6.0.1 not sure if this is the reason

Comment: tweak the answer to: `EnrollmentPlan.joins(:plan).where(plans: { plan_type_id: 1 })`, the first plan matches the association, the plans is for the table regardless of the association, using Rails 6.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I will say use includes instead of joins it will not fire n+1 queries

```
EnrollmentPlan.includes(:plans).where(plans: { plan_type_id: 1 }).references(:plans)
```

Comment: This is more efficient than my solution